# Capturar Nombre de usuario logeado en windows con PHP 5

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache

Estoy desarrollando un sistema bastante simple que no requiere explicación tan profunda, la cuestion es que se me pidio que por cada usuario logeado desde windows (de momento son 2 personas) aparezca en la pagina el nombre de la cuenta que esta logeada en windows.
Por ejemplo :
Pablo inicia sesion en windows y al momento de ingresar el sistema diga (Bienvenido porellana)

Y si Maria ingresa deberia salirle (Bienvenido mpozo) y asi con todos los usuarios, de forma local funciona con esta linea de codigo.

```
   <?php 
       get_current_user();
       $username = get_current_user();
       echo $username;
    ?>
```

Pero al momento de subirlo al servidor que tenemos aca en la empresa siempre me muestra mi nombre de usuario aunque otra persona se conecte con su propia cuenta.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: No sabemos siquiera como esta estructurado tu código y como estas creado la sesión y todo eso, es imposible decirte a ciegas que tienes que hacer.

Comment: te recomiendo leer antes de preguntar, te dejo el manual de la funcion [get_current_user()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-current-user.php) y lo que realmente hace saludos!

Comment: le dejo una imagen mejor para que me entiendan, porellana es el nombre del usuario de mi pc, yo solo quiero que cada usuario distinto que se conecte a mi sistema le aparezca su usuario del pc https://imgur.com/a/vyPWW9K

Comment: ellos no quieren que el usuario inicie sesion, ellos quiere que solamente al momento de ingresar al sistema se les aparezca su nombre de usuario de windows